# In MS Graph API is there a webhook to know who a person is talking to in teams calls?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

When someone calls an employee in our firm, I want to get the phone number of the callee, and using that phone number, a team bot would want to send a proactive message to the employee.

I have all the other bits figured out, except getting the phone number in real-time. Is there a webhook of any sort for this purpose? I know there is a "call records" endpoint...but that's not real-time which can't be used in this use-case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can check [list participants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-list-participants?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) graph API for that

Comment: Is the list participants API real time?

Comment: You cannot get the person is talking when meeting is going on. You can list of participants after the meeting is ended. You can get the list of participants by using [List participants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-list-participants?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API

Comment: Unfortunately, my bot would want to know who the caller is immediately after the call is answered. Not after the meeting/call has ended. Are there any endpoints that provide this functionality?

Comment: Currently there is no API to know the attendees of current call/meeting. Could you please raise a [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform) here?

Comment: Done here: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/41779045-real-time-call-details-in-graph-api